# Celery how to create a task group in a for loop

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I need to create a celery group task where I want to wait for until it has finished, but the docs are not clear to me how to achieve this:

this is my current state:

```
def import_media(request):
    keys = []
    for obj in s3_resource.Bucket(env.str('S3_BUCKET')).objects.all():
        if obj.key.endswith(('.m4v', '.mp4', '.m4a', '.mp3')):
            keys.append(obj.key)
    for key in keys:
        url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
            ClientMethod='get_object',
            Params={'Bucket': env.str('S3_BUCKET'), 'Key': key},
            ExpiresIn=86400,
        )
        if not Files.objects.filter(descriptor=strip_descriptor_url_scheme(url)).exists():
            extract_descriptor.apply_async(kwargs={"descriptor": str(url)})

    return None
```

Now I need to create a new task inside the group for every URL I have, how can I do that?

I Now managed to get my flow working like this:

```
@require_http_methods(("GET"))
def import_media(request):
    keys = []
    urls = []
    for obj in s3_resource.Bucket(env.str('S3_BUCKET')).objects.all():
        if obj.key.endswith(('.m4v', '.mp4', '.m4a', '.mp3')):
            keys.append(obj.key)
    for key in keys:
        url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
            ClientMethod='get_object',
            Params={'Bucket': env.str('S3_BUCKET'), 'Key': key},
            ExpiresIn=86400,
        )
        if not Files.objects.filter(descriptor=strip_descriptor_url_scheme(url)).exists():
            new_file = Files.objects.create(descriptor=strip_descriptor_url_scheme(url))
            new_file.save()
            urls.append(url)
    workflow = (
        group([extract_descriptor.s(url) for url in urls]).delay()
    )
    workflow.get(timeout=None, interval=0.5)
    print("hello - Further processing here")
    return None
```

Any suggestions to optimize this? At least now its working nice!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups

A group runs all tasks despite whether or not any fail, chaining runs the next task if the previous succeeds. What you could do is rather than call apply_async each time in the for loop. You can use the **signature** method which applys the args but doesnt execute the task, until your ready.

```
from celery import group
    ...
    all_urls= []
    for key in keys:
        url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
            ClientMethod='get_object',
            Params={'Bucket': env.str('S3_BUCKET'), 'Key': key},
            ExpiresIn=86400,
        )
        if not Files.objects.filter(descriptor=strip_descriptor_url_scheme(url)).exists():
            all_urls.append(url)
    g = group(extract_descriptor.s(kwargs={"descriptor": str(url)}) for url 
    in all_urls) # create group
    result = g() # you may need to call g.apply_sync(), but this executes all tasks in group
    result.ready()  # have all subtasks completed?
    result.successful() # were all subtasks successful?
```